# R: why the == operator cannot find a value in a numeric vector

Tags: r

I just don get why the following situation can happen.

`X$angle.corrected` is a numeric vector and the value `2399.81` is in it. Why can't the `==` operator find it?

```
> X$angle.corrected[688]
[1] 2399.81
> sum(X$angle.corrected==2399.81)
[1] 0
> class(X$angle.corrected)
[1] "numeric"
```

Comment: Floating point arithmetic is not exact in R (and many other languages).

Comment: as noted in the linked answer, examine `sprintf("%.54f", X$angle.corrected[688])`. Use `all.equal` or define your own equality tolerance.